# How to pass the 'double' userLati, userLong values and String userName to a Json variable /object

Tags: java, json, servlets

In my 'PlayerLocation' servlet, I am getting the 'latitude, longitude and name' as below;

```
     String userLatitude = request.getParameter("currentLat");
     String userLongitude = request.getParameter("currentLong");
     double userLati = Double.parseDouble(userLatitude);         
     double userLong = Double.parseDouble(userLongitude);        
     DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
     userLati= Double.valueOf(dFormat .format(userLati));
     userLong= Double.valueOf(dFormat .format(userLong));
     String userName = request.getParameter("name");
```

I want to receive the latitude, longitude and name in JSP along with servlet response. 
How to pass the 'double' userLati, userLong values and String userName to a Json variable /object   ;

```
        String data =  ///???????
        String json = new Gson().toJson(data);          
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Could someone please advise on how to achieve this  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a pojo of player details and the field should be of respective types that you want in your response. Here is the sample code:

Your PlayerDetails class should look like

```
class PlayerDetails{
private String name;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

    public PlayerDetails(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    //Getter and Setters
}
```

In your servlet do:

```
    PlayerDetails playerDetails=new 
                             PlayerDetails(userName,userLati,userLong);
    String jsonResponse = new Gson().toJson(playerDetails);
```

Now you can write the jsonResponse to response. Sample response of the above code:

```
{
  "name": "user1",
  "latitude": 51.503364,
  "longitude": -0.127625
}
```

PS: One design guideline is you can create a pojo named PlayerLocation with latitude and longitude and let it be a part of PlayerDetails. This will be more cleaner. 
Your json response in such a case would be

```
{
  "name": "user1",
  "location": {
    "latitude": 51.503364,
    "longitude": -0.127625
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use a `HashMap` in this way:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("userLati", 23);
map.put("userLong", 45);
map.put("userName", "mr pro");
String json = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

Comment: This is a bad practice. Please do not use this way.

Comment: @PriyaJain can you tell me more detail? Why it's a bad practice?

Comment: Java is an Object oriented language. Creating a map and putting things into that is indeed the working solution but against the OO principle. The solution should have Classes modeled instead of hardcoded map.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you do

```
class PlayerLocation {
 String currentLat;
 String currentLong;
 String name;

 public PlayerLocation(String currentLat, String currentLong, String name){
  this.currentLat = currentLat;
  this.currentLong = currentLong;
  this.name = name;
 }
}
```

And then change your String data = //??? to a new PlayerLocation object, you can make it look something like:

```
PlayerLocation data = new PlayerLocation(/* data here */);
String json = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

And I think it should work.

I referenced this: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Object-Examples